# Single query result to Multiple CSV files in Powershell

Tags: export-to-csv

I have a query that gives 1.7 million transactions output and this out has be splitted into two files since excel max limit is 1 million. Can you please help me how to do this in powershell. I am unable to figure out with Split_Array function.

Comment: You should know that people living outside India won't have any idea what are "lakh transactions", and definitely no idea what is "10L". So please don't use Indian words like lakh / lac here.

Comment: @JamesZ thanks for the info, sure I will make note of this